# How to play Track when getting Id on Mixradio API

Tags: c#, wpf, mixradio

I'm getting id each items of track but I don't play it as next,back, play, pause...

E.g:
I have items name is **"Blank Space" song** and is **"015668"**. Now. **How to play Blank Space song with id 015668**.

I dont see tutorial about that and Have other media player API support wpf,universal app for mp3 and video stream youtube

Comment: You need to improvise your question to showcase what you have tried and what exactly is failing for you.

Answer (score 0):

The MixRadio API supports playback of 30 second clips within your application - in C#, you would use [this method](http://dev.mixrad.io/doc/netsdk/client.html#GetTrackSampleUri) to get the URI and then play how the platform you're on supports it.